# translate query from Doctrine to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm starting with Doctrine + Symfony and I see that they do queries a bit strange ... could you please "translate" this query to me as it would be in native MYSQL? thank you very much...

```
->addSelect('v')
              ->distinct()
                ->from('Entidades:Viaje', 'v')
                ->innerJoin('v.estadoViaje', 'ev')
                ->innerJoin('v.trayectos', 't')
                ->innerJoin('t.datosTrayecto', 'dt')
                ->innerJoin('dt.estadoTrayecto', 'et')
                //->innerJoin('v.viajesRutaEmpresa', 'vre')
                ->innerJoin('v.rutaEmpresa', 're')
                ->innerJoin('re.empresaSeccion', 'es')
                ->innerJoin('re.ruta', 'r')
                ->innerJoin('t.origen', 'l')
                ->where('es.id = :idEmpresaSeccion')
                ->andWhere('l.id = :idLugar')
                ->andWhere('ev.codigo <> :finalizado')
                ->andWhere('ev.codigo <> :cancelado')
                ->andWhere('et.codigo <> :carretera')
                ->andWhere('v.codigo LIKE :filtroViaje')
                ->andWhere('r.nombre LIKE :filtroRuta')
                ->setParameter('idEmpresaSeccion', $idEmpresaSeccion)
                ->setParameter('idLugar', $idLugar)
                ->setParameter('finalizado', "finalizado")
                ->setParameter('cancelado', "cancelado")
                ->setParameter('carretera', "carretera")
                ->setParameter('filtroViaje', "%" . $filtroViaje . "%")
                ->setParameter('filtroRuta', "%" . $filtroRuta . "%")
                ->orderBy("ev.codigo","ASC")
                ->addOrderBy("v.id", "ASC")
```

Comment: Maybe with [`getSql()`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#building-a-query)?